# Can I detect if a rake task was triggered on the command line (as opposed to with cron, etc.)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Of course it is unusual for rake tasks to be triggered by a controller (and kind of kludgey) but very common for them to be triggered by cron.  I would like to detect from within a rake task whether it was started manually on the command line, or not.

How can I do that?  This is a pretty standard thing to do in a shell script, but I'm unable to find any documentation about how to do it with a rake task.

Why the hate?  People are downgrading this simply because they don't know the answer?  ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a stab I took.

I tested this in both CL and Rails Console. I also tacked an invocation at the end of `Application.rb` to double check. But I haven't tested it in all the *many* other ways one might, so people should use this only with caution.

Likewise, I'm not certain that index 7 will be universal.

But I'm pretty sure it's accomplishable if you really want it.

```
task who_called: :environment do
  puts case caller_locations[7].label
    when "<main>"      then :rails
    when "invoke_task" then :cli
    else
      raise "unknown caller: #{location}"
  end
end
```

---

Another suggestion is to always invoke the task with an ENV variable or an argument. You can assume that `nil` defaults to the command line, so people don't have to type unnecessary arguments.

Comment: Ahh, yeah that's a good idea.  `CRON=1 rake some:task` for example , or `INTERACTIVE=false rake some:task` to make it a little more to-the-point and generic.

Comment: If the index turns out to vary, it would be possible to just cycle through all possible indices to check for the expected values (as long as you can figure out how much variability exists).  But is there any particular reason to expect the index to vary?

Comment: Well, it definitely did when I was using Pry to dig around. Either way, if you compare the stack traces for the two paths, it appears they will be the same up to a certain index. Again, that's just the result of a little casual poking around. I ended up here because I had the same question as you, but after figuring this out, I decided I was over-engineering, and I didn't really need this functionality anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if defined?(Rails::Console) 
  ....
end
```

Or you can check what `caller[0]` returns when you call from the cmd and use that in the if instead.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking.  Note "from within a rake task".  I'm talking about my own rake task that I write.  It needs to detect how it was triggered.  Looking in logs later would be completely useless for my purposes.   That's not "from within a rake task".

Comment: No... the second answer covers that. What I'm basically saying is that yes, there is no built in code which automatically does this for you so you would have to do it manually in the task it self, as you suggest. I guess the answer you were looking for is how to properly log it in the first place. The answer to that is to use kernel#caller. So for example `Rails.logger(caller[0])` This will return the calling method.

Comment: my question doesn't have anything to do with logging.  I want to _detect it from within the rake task_ (so it can interact with the user if there is one there and simply proceed if not).

Comment: I haven't tested it extensively, but it seems like their answers are both largely correct. When you call a task from the command like, `Rails::Console` is not defined. I don't know how that plays out in a production environment, though. Likewise, I don't think `caller[0]` is a useful index, but `caller` and `caller_locations` do have the relevant info, if you're willing to parse them. Again, I don't know if it's practical in the real world. I'm posting an answer with a small job I wrote that uses it.

Comment: @PhillipLongman so are you saying that there's a difference with `Rails::Console` between whether you type the rake command on the command line or it is called from a cron job?  I have a very hard time seeing why it would be different.  Both are using the shell, but one is interactive shell use and the other is not.